# Asymptotic formula for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $1/2<\alpha\leq 1$. How one can compute an asymptotic expansion of series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\sqrt{\epsilon n+1}}, \quad\mbox{ for }\epsilon\to0?
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a not rigorous consideration is acceptable, we can use the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to get the main (divergent) asymptotic term.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\int_1^\infty f(n)dn+\frac{1}{2}f(1)-\frac{1}{12}f'(1)+...$$

In our case $\displaystyle f(n)=\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\sqrt{\epsilon n+1}}$, and we notice that all terms other then integral are not bigger than $\sim O(1)$. Therefore, we can focus on the integral, and using the fact that $\alpha\in (1/2;1]$
$$S(\epsilon, \alpha)\sim\int_1^\infty\frac{dn}{n^{\alpha}\sqrt{\epsilon n+1}}=\epsilon^{\alpha-1}\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{dx}{x^\alpha\sqrt{1+x}}$$
$$=\epsilon^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^\alpha\sqrt{1+x}}-\epsilon^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\epsilon\frac{dx}{x^\alpha\sqrt{1+x}}$$
Integrating and keeping only main terms,
$$S(\epsilon, \alpha)\sim\epsilon^{\alpha-1}B\Big(\alpha-\frac{1}{2};1-\alpha\Big)-\frac{1}{1-\alpha}=\frac{\Gamma\Big(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Gamma(1-\alpha)}{\sqrt\pi}\epsilon^{\alpha-1}-\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$$
In fact, we are not allowed to keep the second term ($\sim O(1)$), but we need it to disclose the uncertainty if $\alpha\to1$:
$$S(\epsilon, \alpha\to1)\sim\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\Big(e^{(\alpha-1)\ln\epsilon}\,\Gamma\big(1+(1-\alpha)\big)-1\Big)\sim\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$
Therefore,
$$S(\epsilon; \alpha)\sim\frac{\Gamma\big(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\big)\,\Gamma(1-\alpha)}{\sqrt\pi}\,\epsilon^{\alpha-1};\quad \alpha\in(1/2;1)$$
$$S(\epsilon; \alpha=1)\sim\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

Comment: I may be totally stupid but I have a problem with your last line. If $\alpha=1$ the integral is $$2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)=(2 \log (2)-\log (\epsilon ))+\frac{\epsilon }{2}+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, thank you for corrections! Yes, the answer should be $\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ - I made a mistake with sign; just correcting. The sign is clear also from the fact that the sum is positive :)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, BTW, the difference 0.5 you mentioned in your evaluation comes from the second term of the Euler-Maclaurin formula: $\frac{1}{2}(f(1)+f(∞))=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

Doing the same as @Svyatoslav in his good answer, we could easily use all terms given in the linked Wikipedia page since the odd order derivatives of $f(n)$ at $n=1$ are quite simple
$$f'(1)=-\frac{\alpha }{(\epsilon   +1)^{1/2}}-\frac{\epsilon }{2 (\epsilon   +1)^{3/2}}$$
$$f'''(1)=-\frac{\alpha  (\alpha
   +1) (\alpha +2)}{(\epsilon   +1)^{1/2}}-\frac{3 \alpha 
   (\alpha +1) \epsilon }{2 (\epsilon +1)^{3/2}}-\frac{9 \alpha  \epsilon ^2}{4 (\epsilon +1)^{5/2}}-\frac{15 \epsilon ^3}{8
   (\epsilon +1)^{7/2}}$$ and so on to obtain
$$\frac{\Gamma (1-\alpha )  \,\,\Gamma \left(\alpha
   -\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\,\epsilon ^{\alpha -1}+\sum_{k=0}^? \frac {\alpha-k} {\alpha-(k+1)}\,P_k(\alpha)\,\epsilon^k$$ Using Euler–Maclaurin summationformula up to $f^{(5)}$ included, the $P_k(\alpha)$ are polynomials of degree $5$ in $\alpha$.

Limited to $O(\epsilon^2)$, this gives
$$\frac{\Gamma (1-\alpha )\,\, \Gamma \left(\alpha
   -\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\,\epsilon ^{\alpha -1}+$$
$$\frac{(\alpha +2) (\alpha +4) (\alpha +6) (\alpha +7) ((\alpha -10) \alpha   +45)}{30240 (\alpha -1)}+$$
$$-\frac{(\alpha +1) (\alpha +3) (\alpha +5) (\alpha +6) ((\alpha -12) \alpha   +56)}{60480 (\alpha -2)}\,\epsilon
+O(\epsilon^2)$$

Trying for $\epsilon=10^{-3}$ and a few values of $\alpha$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha &\text{approximation} & \text{"exact"} \\
 0.51 & 2991.90 & 2991.90\\
 0.52 & 1416.18 & 1416.18 \\
 0.53 & 894.308 & 894.308 \\
 0.54 & 635.723 & 635.722 \\
 0.55 & 482.325 & 482.324 \\
 0.60 & 186.742 & 186.742 \\
 0.65 & 97.9526 & 97.9519 \\
 0.70 & 58.7709 & 58.7701 \\
 0.75 & 38.2647 & 38.2638 \\
 0.80 & 26.4109 & 26.4099 \\
 0.85 & 19.0845 & 19.0833 \\
 0.90 & 14.3266 & 14.3253 \\
 0.95 & 11.1139 & 11.1123 \\
 0.96 & 10.6013 & 10.5997 \\ 
 0.97 & 10.1237 & 10.1221 \\
 0.98 & 9.67820 & 9.67653 \\
 0.99 & 9.26217 & 9.26046 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**For the case where $\alpha=1$**

This case is simple since the integral is just
$$2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)$$
Repeating the same process, the asymptotics is
$$\frac{1459}{2520}+\log \left(\frac{4}{\epsilon }\right)+\frac{\epsilon
   }{4}-\frac{\epsilon ^2}{32}+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$ which gives $8.87327$ if  $\epsilon=10^{-3}$ (the "exact" value  being $8.87152$) and $15.7808$  if  $\epsilon=10^{-6}$ (the "exact" value  being $15.7790$)